# MySQL Or condition on two columns that may be empty

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table `customers` that has a column `email_address` and `contact_number` and only one of them is required.

Now I want to write a Query to check if the customer exists.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer c
WHERE (c.email_address = '' OR c.contact_number = '0123456789')
AND c.company_id = companyId
```

This works fine if the customer record have both a email address and contact number, but if the customer only has one of them (e.g. email_address = '' and contact_number = '1234567890' ) it returns a result which is correct, but I would like it to not check the column if `email_address` or `contact_number` is empty or null.

**Edit:**
Here is some sample data and examples of the result I would like:

Table: customer

id, email_address, contact_number, company_id

1, '', '0123456789', 1

2, 'aa@aa.aa', '', 1

3, 'cc@cc.cc', '2345678901', 1

if I give the query the email address: 'aa@aa.aa' and contact number: '' it must return customer 2

if I give the query the email address: '' and contact number: '2345678901' it must return customer 3

if I give the query the email address: 'cc@cc.cc' and contact number: '0123456789' it must return customer 1 and 3

if I give the query the email address: 'cc@cc.cc' and contact number: '2345678901123123132' it must return customer 3

if I give the query the email address: 'xx@cc.dd' and contact number: '234567890112312313223' it must return no customer

Comment: how do you identify a customer? do you have a email and phone number and want to search for a customer that has one of them set?

Comment: @MPK1 the customer is identified by a id, but I want to check before inserting if the email or contact number exists already. I basically want to search for a customer that has one of them set or both.

Comment: I don't really get why you're not happy with your code. You said "...it returns a result which is correct, but I would like it to not check the column if email_address or contact_number is empty or null.". If the result is "correct", which other result do you want to have?

Comment: @Think_Twice can you add some data and expected result as well, in text format

Comment: @ErgestBasha I added some sample data and example/expected results

Comment: @Think_Twice with your new example stuff I'm pretty sure your SQL returns exactly what you're looking for. Can you give one specific example in which your current code does not return what it should?

Comment: @MPK1 it doesn't work if I give it a contact number but no email address. With no email address and given a contact number, it return the customers with that contact number but also the customers with no email. So mainly my issue is handling the blank columns or making it ignore customers with a empty email or contact number.

Comment: Ah, now I got your point, wait a sec...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're probably searching for:

Input: `EMAIL` and `PHONE`

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer c
WHERE
(
     (c.email_address = 'EMAIL' AND 'EMAIL' <> '')
  OR (c.contact_number = 'PHONE' AND 'PHONE' <> '')
)
AND c.company_id = companyId
```